# Rails, ESBuild source map is always missing, but it is in the build

Tags: ruby-on-rails, source-maps, esbuild

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/application.js-1246371c75312771378dc97fa604ef404c73f9b477b5eb8f4c6ebb2fd2e1e323.map"):
```

My build script in package.json is:

```
"build": "esbuild app/javascript/*.* --bundle --sourcemap --outdir=app/assets/builds",
```

So I see under assets, under builds, my application.js, and my application.js.map

But developer console shows 404 on the source map, and the server logs show that resource as an error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried `rake webpacker:clobber` and `rake webpacker:compile` to compile everything again?

Comment: I am not using webpacker. The whole point of this exercise is to use esbuild.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you resolve this? Thanks

Comment: Nope. I just remove the --sourcemap from the ESBuild as it clearly does not work for whatever reason. Maybe a newer version will fix that someday. For now though, that solved my problem.

Comment: oh, got the same issue.... but removing the --sourcemap  didn't change anything.

but there is a corresponding .map file created, it just doesn't have the long timestamp, file is named "application-esbuild.js.map", but browser tries to get "application-esbuild.js-23a1629fa27d6de04ef39a3ad6fdfdec018b3d3ffdc238508aab65be1240dc3e.map"

Comment: So do you think this is solvable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Corresponding to [this thread](https://github.com/rails/jsbundling-rails/issues/73)

Setting `config.assets.debug = false` will solve that error

Answer (score 2):

The `config.assets.debug = false` workaround has undesirable side effects. Missing debug log messages etc.

A cleaner [solution](https://github.com/rails/jsbundling-rails/issues/40#issuecomment-1176856408) is to add the following route definition to `config/routes.rb`:

```
if Rails.env.development?
  redirector = ->(params, _) { ApplicationController.helpers.asset_path("#{params[:name].split('-').first}.map") }
  constraint = ->(request) { request.path.ends_with?(".map") }
  get "assets/*name", to: redirect(redirector), constraints: constraint
end
```

This resolves the sourcemaps for JS and CSS files and keeps asset debugging intact.